# Pointers being declared in structs in c

Tags: c

```
    struct charact
{
    char ch;
    int occurs;
    struct charact *next;
};
```

What is "next" in this struct exactly?

Comment: You have written already yourself: it is a declaration of a pointer.

Comment: So what;s the difference between name and this :

Comment: typedef struct charact Char;
typedef Char * ListofChar;

Comment: name vs ListofChar?

Comment: In the first case the pointer is a data member of the structure. In the second case there is declared a pointer to an object of the structure type.

Comment: So what is the syntax of a variable of ListofChar, should we decide to use it to point somewhere to Chars?

Comment: "So what;s the difference between name and this :" `typedef struct charact Char; typedef Char * ListofChar; ` - One of them horridly hides a pointer type in a typedef alias, the other doesn't. That's the difference. And the confusion you're experiencing is *directly* because of that fact. When you see `Char *` or `struct charact *` you *know* what they are; *pointer* types. When you see `ListofChar` in code, without backtracking, you have no *clue* what it is without deciphering the surrounding context. Don't fall into that pit; friends don't let friends hide pointer types in typedef aliases.

Answer (score 3):

> What is "next" in this struct exactly?

`next` is a `struct charact` pointer. It can be used to point at instances of `struct charact` or `NULL` to indicate that it's not pointing at a `struct charact`.

This particular `struct` looks like it is a *node* in a *forward linked list*. That is, a linked list that only has references to the next element in the list.

A *(double) linked list* would also have a `struct charact` pointer to be able to point at the previous element in the list:

```c
struct charact
{
    char ch;
    int occurs;
    struct charact *prev;
    struct charact *next;
};
```

For such a node, linking them together could look like this:

```
struct charact a = {.ch = 'a'};
struct charact b = {.ch = 'b'};
struct charact c = {.ch = 'c'};
a.next = &b;
b.prev = &a;
b.next = &c;
c.prev = &b;

struct charact *head = &a;
struct charact *tail = &c;
```

Here `head` would point at `a`. `a.next` points at `b` and `b.next` points at `c` - and you would have the ability to go backwards in such a list too via the `prev` member:

```cpp
// backwards:
for(struct charact *curr = tail; curr != NULL; curr = curr->prev) {
    printf("%c\n", curr->ch);
}

// forward:
for(struct charact *curr = head; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next) {
    printf("%c\n", curr->ch);
}
```

Note: The actual instances of list nodes are usually not created as automatic variables like above but created and destroyed dynamically using `malloc`/`free`.